# socket.io - .on not working on client side

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have some very basic code that uses socket.io

**Client**

```
var socket = io();

// Do some stuff...

socket.emit('hello', 'please like me');

// Wait for a response
socket.on('hello back!', function(msg) {
    console.log('Yay, he replied:', msg);
});
```

**Server**

```
var app = require('express');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('a user connected');

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('user disconnected');
    });

    socket.on('hello', function() {
        // Code to decide wether or not I like the client
        // ...
        // I do like the client!
        socket.emit('hello back!', 'how are you');
        console.log('I said hello back!');
    });
});
```

Hopefully you managed to get the picture. So ideally, this would happen:

1. Client connects
2. After a while, client emits `hello`
3. Server sees this, emits `hello back!`
4. Client notices the `hello back!` event
5. Everyone is happy!

But this isn't the case for me unfortunately. Instead, steps 1-3 work perfectly. But when you reach step 4 and 5, things start to fall apart. Client never logs anything after `hello back!` event is emitted.

This is *not* my full code, I figured it would make it easier for you to understand it. It's very possible that I've made some silly mistake somewhere, maybe without including it in this code. But please let me know if there is anything fundamentally wrong with what I am doing.

Cheers

Comment: There isn't anything obviously wrong in this sample of code so it's probably related to something in your real code that isn't shown here.  I would suggest moving the `socket.on('hello back!', ...)` before the `socket.emit('hello', ...)` so you're sure the listener for the response is in place before you send the message, but that's probably not the main issue.

Comment: @jfriend00 will do, thanks so much for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is a few years old, but in case anyone stumbles across this in the future:

My problem had nothing to do with my code shown above. Instead, it was a configuration error.

I was hosting my project on glitch.com who state that they support websockets, but the error was caused because the server was not able to get across to the client (client never received any data from server at all after websocket connection was opened).

This was an error that I had in 2018 with glitch.com, and I know that other people have had it too. It also seemed to be related somehow to websockets connecting via a domain name and with SSL, but I can't recall the exact circumstances.